# Unable to get the output as expected in XSLT

Tags: xslt

can you help me to get the expected output:

No Restriction to use XSLT 2.0

Conditions:

contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'H') then Its Header

contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'D') Then Its details and its multiple records between Header and Trailer

contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'D') then Trailer

Input:

```html
<Root-Element>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000001</C1>
    <C2>H</C2>
    <C3/>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000002</C1>
    <C2>D</C2>
    <C3>20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</C3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 1120210132015000003</C1>
    <C2>D</C2>
    <C3>20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</C3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000007</C1>
    <C2>T</C2>
    <C3>000000138000000002885156</C3>
  </test>

  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000001</C1>
    <C2>H</C2>
    <C3/>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000002</C1>
    <C2>D</C2>
    <C3>20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</C3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 1120210132015000003</C1>
    <C2>D</C2>
    <C3>20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</C3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 1120210132015000004</C1>
    <C2>D</C2>
    <C3>20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</C3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <C1>CCO 11220210132015000007</C1>
    <C2>T</C2>
    <C3>000000138000000002885155</C3>
  </test>
</Root-Element>
```

XSLT :

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/Root-Element">
    <Details>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="test" />
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test[contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'H')]">
    <Header>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test[contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'D')]">
    <Details>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <!--xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::test[contains(C1,'000003') and contains(C2,'D')][1]/*"/-->
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test[contains(C1,'00000') and contains(C2,'T')]">
    <Control>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Control>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test" />


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Received Output

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Details>
  <Header>CCO 11220210132015000001H</Header>
  <Details>CCO 11220210132015000002D20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</Details>
  <Details>CCO 1120210132015000003D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
  <Control>CCO 11220210132015000007T000000138000000002885156</Control>
  <Header>CCO 11220210132015000001H</Header>
  <Details>CCO 11220210132015000002D20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</Details>
  <Details>CCO 1120210132015000003D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
  <Details>CCO 1120210132015000004D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
  <Control>CCO 11220210132015000007T000000138000000002885155</Control>
</Details>
```

Expected Output:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Details>
  <Batch>
    <Header>CCO 11220210132015000001H</Header>
    <Details>CCO 11220210132015000002D20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</Details>
    <Details>CCO 1120210132015000003D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
    <Control>CCO 11220210132015000007T000000138000000002885156</Control>
  </Batch>
  <Batch>
    <Header>CCO 11220210132015000001H</Header>
    <Details>CCO 11220210132015000002D20220210132015594860990011000000053002000020220210081075140001000002 Y</Details>
    <Details>CCO 1120210132015000003D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
    <Details>CCO 1120210132015000004D20220210132015577823920019000000047002000020220210081075140002000003 Y</Details>
    <Control>CCO 11220210132015000007T000000138000000002885155</Control>
  </Batch>
</Details>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XSLT 2.0+ then this is a case for `<xsl:for-each-group selec="test" group-starting-with="test[C2='H']">`

If you're still on XSLT 1.0 then I'm afraid it's not easy. Look up "sibling recursion" for ideas.

Please, in XSLT questions, always state if there's a constraint on which version you can use. Many problems like this become vastly easier with 2.0 or 3.0.

**==UPDATE==**

With XSLT 2.0+, this would be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Root-Element">
 <Details>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="test" 
        group-starting-with="test[C2='H']">
     <Batch>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
     </Batch>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </Details>
</xsl:template>
```

followed by your template rules for `test` elements as before.

Comment: I don't have any restriction Michael, can you suggest logic with for-each grouping